# Flutter stable version 1.20.1 build failed issue

Tags: flutter

I update the Flutter latest stable version 1.20.1 when I click the run button on an already existing project it shows me this error:

> Could not resolve the package 'characters' in 'package: characters/characters.dart'.

But when I create a new project and try to run it works.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running `flutter clean` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the Github issue below, it is a common issue after upgrading to a different `Flutter Version`

[Could not resolve package characters](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59645)

In my case, I resolved the issue with `flutter clean`.